# Van office, DIY or bought?

Tags: budget, automobiles, road-trips

First, this is more of a *"What-if"* type of question, open for discussion.

I am currently a student at a German university and I dream of working remotely, in the IT sector, from a van, so that I am not bound to stay in one place and can work from wherever I want. Obviously, I would need a van for that. And now the question I am currently thinking about is whether I should try to buy a simple van and convert it so that I could live in it or buy an already converted van, from a specialized company.
I have basic woodworking and electricity skills, but not anything in the direction of plumbing, etc.
The aspects I am thinking about are:

- Budget
- Quality
- Personalization
- Usefulness

In my opinion, an already converted van will be of higher build quality, as when I try to build it completely with skills taken from YouTube. On the other hand, I reckon it will be less expensive, to build it by myself, if I can do it without any faults, and more personalized and useful because I would work it out exactly how I need it. For example, currently, I don't have any idea how you would install the water tanks for the fresh and used water and connect them in the right way to the sink or toilet.

So with that said, my question is, does any of you have experience with this sort of thing, and can tell me something about it? I am very happy to get inspiration and ideas from you or maybe just a link to a blog that would be useful on that topic.

Edit 1:
With "Van" I mean a vehicle that is similar to a VW Crafter or Mercedes Sprinter. Just under the 3.5 ton limit. But not like a usual VW T6.

Thank you

Comment: When you say “van”, what kind of size are you thinking of? What most people would call a “van” would not have a sink or toilet (people then use public facilities), you seem to be more in “mobile home” territory there. Also remember that in many places (especially the nicest ones) there are lots of restrictions on where cans and mobile homes are allowed to park, stay overnight, or even drive. And if you plan to work from it, remember that you will need a power source.

Comment: @jcaron with "van" i mean something like a VW Crafter or Mercedes Sprinter. Under the 3,5 ton limit of the German drivers license. I am aware about the power, there was once a nice article in a tech magazine a friend sent me.

Comment: You'll need an address for your identity, and mail. There are many practical problems, such as siting, laundry, water and electricity supply, toilet emptying, delivery of online purchases, hassle from police, and so on. I once converted a small lorry and lived in it for a while, but enjoyed doing the conversion more. I moved out on Christmas Day when the gas bottle froze. Later, I went deeply into the idea of living on a boat, but there are the same practical problems. They are leisure activities, and paying for moorings or siting can be just as expensive as renting a small apartment.

Comment: @jcaron motorhome rather than mobile home, at least in. British English. Mobile homes aren't very mobile (it's another name for static caravan). Staying under 3.5 T avoids a lot of daytime restrictions, but height barriers on car parks are an issue, and vans new enough for clean air zones are expensive even 2nd hand

Comment: I voted to close for "needs more focus." As it stands, the question is a perfect example of the "Let's talk about x" questions specifically called out in the [Help pages](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) as off-topic, for discussion, breadth, and "could write a book about it" aspects.

Comment: Check out Ladi&Margaret on Youtube, they did their van DIY and have it well documented.

Answer (score 3):

I converted a 3.5 tonne Transit medium wheelbase a few years ago. We designed it for use mainly on campsites, but I've done the odd night in car parks in the UK. Campsites are preferable if you're spending more than one night in it, but full time van life is not uncommon here.

Mine is big enough to have a retractable double bed and a kitchen with fridge, sink, and (when you've got mains power) oven/microwave. It's also got a toilet but no shower.

The  cassette toilet (look then up) has its own tank for flush water as well as a waste holding tank. Fresh water can use a tank built underneath, or in my case a 25l container in a cupboard. Either way it's pumped to the tap. Waste water goes into a similar container, though tanks underneath are possible. External tanks are tricky, and prone to freezing.

As far the as the office side of things, that needs power, and I doubt you'll generate enough with solar even covering the whole roof. So that pushes you onto campsites again. Generators are a bad idea as it makes you very obvious;the noise is also antisocial. You'll also have to put some thought into the ergonomics of your workspace.

Conversion is fairly hard work - nearly every weekend for a year, with a decent range of tools and a driveway to work on. The windows and respray were the only things we paid to have done.

Comment: This only really scratches the surface of the practical aspects, and for you the legal, logistical, and social side would also be important. I don't know about the situation in Germany but I wouldn't be optimistic